# django-pipeline does not work

Tags: django, django-pipeline

I am trying to make django-pipeline works but it just does not work. Below is my seetting. I added 'pipeline' in the apps section.

This is the error when I attempt to open my site:
**'Settings' object has no attribute 'PIPELINE'**

Below is my setting:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_cdn')

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineCachedStorage'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'pipeline.finders.PipelineFinder',
)

PIPELINE_JS = {
    'stats': {
        'source_filenames': (
          'js/base.js',
        ),
        'output_filename': 'site-js-min.js',
    }
}


PIPELINE_CSS = {
    'colors': {
        'source_filenames': (
          'css/base.css',
        ),
        'output_filename': 'site-css-min.css',
        'variant': 'datauri',
        'extra_context': {
            'media': 'screen,projection',
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The syntax has changed with the new versions [Upgrading from 1.5](http://django-pipeline.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#upgrading-from-1-5)

Answer (score 5):

[As per the docs](https://django-pipeline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html), you need to define `PIPELINE` variable in `settings.py` which looks like,

```
PIPELINE = {
    'PIPELINE_ENABLED': True,
    'JAVASCRIPT': {
        'stats': {
            'source_filenames': (
              'js/jquery.js',
              'js/d3.js',
              'js/collections/*.js',
              'js/application.js',
            ),
            'output_filename': 'js/stats.js',
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!